# Supressing sonar warnings in css/scss files?

Tags: css, sass, sonarqube

We have an angular 7 application where we have defined a component of our own called `ZisIconComponent`. We are using it in another component as follows:

```
<div class="information">
  <zis-icon icon='mark'></zis-icon>{{output.summary}}
</div>
```

in the corresponding `scss` file we have the following:

```
.information {
  zis-icon {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}
```

This works exactly as intended. However, Sonarqube (which is part of our corporate build environment) complains about the styling instructions:

> Unexpected unknown type selector "zis-icon" (css:S4670)

As a consequence, our build breaks. If this were a java file, I could solve this by using

```
@SuppressWarning("css:S4670")
```

but I have not found a way to do the same in css/scss files.

Searching the net has brought me to [this post](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-css-suppress-sonar-rule-in-code/11598), but that only shows somebody else having the same problem without giving a solution.

Can this be done?

Or is my only solution the exclusion of all css/scss files from sonar analysis?

Comment: You may be interested in [this Community post](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/stop-flagging-valid-custom-web-component-tag-names-with-s4670/30262) I just made.  The rule should not be flagging valid custom component names.

Comment: Thank you @Coderer, I'm looking forward to the response you'll get from the team over there.